# Package witharrows and class standalone - Missing arrow in the output

Tags: standalone, witharrows

The following code doesn't give the expected result.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}

$\begin{WithArrows}
A & = (a+1)^2 \Arrow[tikz=thick]{we expand} \\
  & = a^2 + 2a + 1
\end{WithArrows}$

\end{document}
```

In the output, the arrow is missing. This surely comes from the different compilations needed to add the arrow.

[image]

Is there an "automatic" way to fix that?

Comment: The arrows and the comments are, by design, not taken into account for determining the bounding box. They would be with `DispWithArrows*`, but in this case the result is a whole line. I see nothing in the manual that can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this "trick".

Comment: With the class option `varwidth` and `DispWithArrows*` one gets an output where the arrow isn't missing. That result can be cropped by an external tool.

Comment: This is a good solution. Indeed, I will do that systematically to avoid the kind of breaking noticed here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written a new version of `witharrows` (v. 2.8 of 2023/01/01). That version provides a new key `right-overlap`. When that key is set to `false` (with `\WithArrowsOptions` or for an individual environment `{WithArrows}`), the  arrows are longer drawn on an overlapping position on the right.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{witharrows}

\WithArrowsOptions{right-overlap=false}

\begin{document}

$\begin{WithArrows}
A & = (a+1)^2 \Arrow[tikz=thick]{we expand} \\
  & = a^2 + 2a + 1
\end{WithArrows}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 4):

Not automatic, but you can manually adjust the bounding box with the `border` option of standalone. I also added some padding to the left and top, feel free to make those 0pt.

```
\documentclass[border={2pt 0pt 60pt 2pt}]{standalone}
% border={left bottom right top}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}

$\begin{WithArrows}
A & = (a+1)^2 \Arrow[tikz=thick]{we expand} \\
  & = a^2 + 2a + 1
\end{WithArrows}$

\end{document}
```

[image: pic]

Comment: A starting point.